# Which is/which are the antonym/antonyms of "to narrow down"?

Tags: antonyms

**Example**: "In order to narrow down your search, you should ...".

How would a native speaker say the exact opposite?

Comment: Not native speaker myself, but I would guess: *broaden*, *extend*, *expand*.

Comment: I'd go for 'widen', but why are you comparing the two?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Thanks for the comment, that was because I didn't know how to say that, while I knew how to say the opposite, so I compared the two in order to express what I needed to know

Comment: Perhaps somebody can explain me the reason of the downvote? Would this question fit better on "English Language Learners"? If so I apologize, I tought here would have been a good place to ask question like this one. A moderator should feel free to move this to the most appropriate site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Expand* or *broaden* would be appropriate antonyms to *narrow down*.